# Header and Footer Fragments in SAPUI5

Tags: xml, model-view-controller, sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide

I'm new in SAPUI5, and I'm wondering if is it possible to have my header and footer as a Fragments?
And if it's possible then how?

This is my `Worklist.view.xml`:

```xml
<mvc:View controllerName="opensap.manageproducts.ManageProducts.controller.Worklist" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:semantic="sap.f.semantic" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <semantic:SemanticPage id="page" headerPinnable="false" toggleHeaderOnTitleClick="false">
        <core:Fragment fragmentName="opensap.manageproducts.ManageProducts.view.Header" type="XML"/>
        <semantic:content>
            <IconTabBar id="iconTabBar" select="onQuickFilter" expandable="false" applyContentPadding="false">
                <items>
                    <IconTabFilter key="all" showAll="true" count="{i18n>worklistFilterProductsAllCount}" text="{i18n>worklistFilterProductsAll}"/>
                    <IconTabSeparator/>
                    <IconTabFilter key="cheap" icon="sap-icon://waiver" iconColor="Positive" count="{worklistView>/cheap}" text="{i18n>worklistFilterCheap}"/>
                    <IconTabFilter key="moderate" icon="sap-icon://loan" iconColor="Critical" count="{worklistView>/moderate}"
                        text="{i18n>worklistFilterModerate}"/>
                    <IconTabFilter key="expensive" icon="sap-icon://money-bills" iconColor="Negative" count="{worklistView>/expensive}"
                        text="{i18n>worklistFilterExpensive}"/>
                </items>
```

And here's my fragment `Header.fragment.xml`:

```xml
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:semantic="sap.f.semantic">
        <Title text="Hello world" level="H2"/>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

It shows me an empty Header.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is the fragment, as long as this `opensap.manageproducts.ManageProducts.view.Header` is the location of you fragment it should work.

The problem is the header and footer. You are using a SemanticPage, see the API Reference: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.f.semantic.SemanticPage%23aggregations

The available aggregations are `headerContent`, `footerCustomActions`, `footerMainAction`.

It depends on what you want to show in you header and footer.

For example, if it's only the title you should use the `titleHeading`, `titleExpandedContent` etc. Than it doesn't really make sense to put it inside a fragment, as the code will only be:

```
<semantic:titleHeading>
  <Title text="{/title}" />
</semantic:titleHeading>
```

But if you want to define the headerContent for example, it will make more sense to, because it will go from:

```
        <semantic:headerContent>
            <layout:HorizontalLayout allowWrapping="true">
                <layout:VerticalLayout class="sapUiMediumMarginEnd">
                    <ObjectAttribute title="Functional Area" text="{/objectDescription/category}"/>
                    <ObjectAttribute title="Cost Center" text="{/objectDescription/center}"/>
                    <ObjectAttribute title="Email" text="{/objectDescription/email}"/>
                </layout:VerticalLayout>

                <layout:VerticalLayout>
                    <ObjectAttribute title="Availability"/>
                    <ObjectStatus text="In Stock" state="{/objectDescription/status}" />
                </layout:VerticalLayout>
            </layout:HorizontalLayout>
        </semantic:headerContent>
```

to:

```
        <semantic:headerContent>
            <core:Fragment fragmentName="opensap.manageproducts.ManageProducts.view.Header" type="XML"/>
        </semantic:headerContent>
```

So just to answer you question, yes it's possible to use a fragment for the header/footer, but what you're missing is the correct aggregation. For some examples you can also look at this link:https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.f.semantic.SemanticPage

Comment: I want to create a header with logo and Title and Navigation Bar that's why I need to create a fragment and use it in all the pages. Is it possible to use the aggregations of the semanticPage control in the fragment?

Comment: Ah I get what you're trying to do now. In this case you would just want to use routing. Then you will have a single "App.view.xml" where you define your header and footer. And in the other views just a section gets replaced. Take al ook at this tutorial from sapui5: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/1b6dcd39a6a74f528b27ddb22f15af0d